# How to setup the "onChange" trigger in Google Sheet script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get a Google sheet's cell background color hex code into that same cell.

This is the function I currently use:

```
  function BGHEX(row, column) {
  var background = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getCell(row, column).getBackground();
  return background;
}
```

Now I have 2 issues:

1. I need the function to run again when the cell's background color is edited. I know I need to use the installable trigger "onChange" but no idea how to set it up.
2. I need this script & function to run on a duplicate of this Google Sheet file (meaning other sheet id's).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable. If you need further help, show what you tried and add a brief description of you search efforts as is suggested in [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps to setup an onChange trigger in your spreadsheet

> 1. Open your Apps Script project.
> 2. At the left, click Triggers alarm.
> 3. At the bottom right, click Add Trigger.
> 4. Select and configure the type of trigger you want to create.
> 5. Click Save.

Your trigger setup should look like this:

[image]

To detect background change in your spreadsheet, you need to have an **Event Object** to determine which changeType the user made. For this scenario, we need '**FORMAT**'.

Also, to change the background color of a cell or range, the user must click or highlight the range. Using `getActiveRange()` will help us determine which range is being edited.

**Code:**

```
function onBGChange(e) {
  if(e.changeType == 'FORMAT')
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().getBackground());
}
```

**Example:**

*Here I change the background color of A1*

[image]

**Output:**

**Executions Tab:**

[image]

To apply this to another spreadsheet, you need to replicate the code and trigger set up. A script is bound to the spreadsheet where it was created and functions like `getActive()` and `getActiveRange()` will only work on the spreadsheet the script was bound to.

References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
- [getActiveRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getactiverange)