# onEdit trigger based on OUTCOME (VALUE) from formula result

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to create an AUTOSORT `onEdit`() script that is only triggered when a value in Column D (4) matches a certain text. In this pattern, when the `onEdit` trigger becomes active, `range.sort({column:11,ascending:true})` is used in the active sheet, but is limited to a preselected range of sheets.

I have a script for when a cell is changed completely, but unfortunately doesn't run when the value is changed due to a formula.

*What I would like to have is a script that checks the outcome of a formula for a specific TEXT in Column D (4) whenever it is changed.*

### What I have so far (not working at this moment):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}

function multiSortColumns(e) {
  if (e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.getValue() == 'CHANGE OF DATE') {
    var sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,];
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
    if (sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
      range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
      e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: About `What I would like to have is a script that checks the outcome of a formula for a specific TEXT in Column D (4) whenever it is changed.`, in your situation, when is the formula recalculated?

Comment: The formula is recalculated based on the outcome of a different cell. So, when the Index Match of that other cell (let's call it X) returns a certain date, this will impact the outcome of the targeted cell (let's call it A). I need the value in cell A.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you want to use OnEdit trigger, it is required to manually edit the cell. OnEdit trigger cannot be fired by the change of the formula. So, from `The formula is recalculated based on the outcome of a different cell.`, I thought that in that case, it is required to know the manually edited cell.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value in column D is not manually edited but through a formula or function, onEdit(e) doesn't consider that as an event as explained in the [limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) below:

```
- Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.
```

But let's say the cell that is manually edited is in column A and based on that, the cell value in the same row in column D changes to "CHANGE OF DATE", you can adjust your code by catching that edit event in column A :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  multiSortColumns(e);
}

function multiSortColumns(e) {
  //var refcell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();

  if (e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.offset(0,3).getValue() == 'CHANGE OF DATE') {  //i.e. col 1 is edited and col 1+3 shows "CHANGE OF DATE"

    var sheets = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", , ,];
    var sheet = e.range.getSheet();

    if (sheets.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
      var range = sheet.getRange("A5:bY600");
      range.sort({ column: 11, ascending: true });
      e.source.toast('Sort complete.');
    }
    
  }
}
```

Your column D is still used as a pre-condition for sorting but using offset() relative to column A where the edit event actually happened.

Comment: What if I use an onChange script for changes in a sheet with importrange? Everytime something changes with the data extracted with importrange, the script above is activated. What about that? How would that look like in a script?

Comment: I have used the other installable triggers except onChange so I won't have an outright answer, unfortunately. I suggest you experiment with onChange to see if it could work. Here's one related example for your ref [link[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67318795/how-to-setup-the-onchange-trigger-in-google-sheet-script-editor). My hunch is that the event should still be triggered with a user-triggered change but let me know if otherwise.

Comment: Looking at the Event Objects documentation, there are specific types of changes that can be detected so just see what could work in your situation. The link can be found in the previous reference. Hope this helps.